# Calculate distance from GPX in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, distance

I have a little OL script to display GPX Routes in a OSM map. That works so far, even with a little gimmick.

What I miss is a continuous distance. So from trkpt 0 to trkpt 1 + (trkpt 1 to trkpt 2) + (trkpt 2 to trkpt 3) etc.

For the gimmick I use the array keys. Each array key is an (internal) point where data is calculated. In OpenLayers is an array with all coordinates + the elevation. I would like to extend this array by the distance. Whether the array values should be the continuous distance or that from last-trkpt to next-trkpt, I would have to think twice. Maybe a value with last-trkpt to next-trkpt is probably better.

Is there a solution without OL npm. I use only the ol.css and ol.js v5.3.0.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" >
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var gpxFormat = new ol.format.GPX();
var gpxFeatures;
var coordsarray = [];
var GPXgeometry = [];
function handleFileSelect(evt) {

gpxLayer.getSource().clear();

var files = evt.target.files;

var output = [];
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(files[i], "UTF-8");
reader.onload = function (evt) {
gpxFeatures = gpxFormat.readFeatures(evt.target.result,{
dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
featureProjection:'EPSG:3857'
});
gpxLayer.getSource().addFeatures(gpxFeatures);

var features = gpxLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
features.forEach(function(feature) {
GPXgeometry = feature.getGeometry();
coordsarray = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
});

//--- ??? Start

var i = 0;
var distance = 0;
coordsarray[0][i].push(distance):

// for ???

var lat0 = coordsarray[0][i][0];
var lon0 = coordsarray[0][i][1];
var latlon0 = [lat0, lon0];
i++;
var lat1 = coordsarray[0][i][0];
var lon1 = coordsarray[0][i][1];
var latlon1 = [lat1, lon1];

// calculate distance
// ???

coordsarray[0][i].push(distance):
i--;

//--- ??? End

}


var gpxLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({

})
});


var map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',
layers: [
new ol.layer.Tile({
source: new ol.source.OSM()
}),
gpxLayer
]
});

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Example of var coordsarray:

```
console.log(coordsarray[0][0][0]); // -37937.014545402875
console.log(coordsarray[0][0][1]); // 5354259.990656373
console.log(coordsarray[0][0][2]); // 188.5
console.log(coordsarray[0][1][0]); // -37936.012669985736
console.log(coordsarray[0][1][1]); // 5354231.092259876
console.log(coordsarray[0][1][2]); // 188.5
```

**EDIT**
GPX Example (near equador)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- track-length = 1323 filtered ascend = 0 plain-ascend = -1 cost=4036 energy=.0kwh time=9.9m -->
<gpx 
 xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" 
 creator="BRouter-1.4.11" version="1.1">
 <trk>
  <name>brouter_trekking_0</name>
  <trkseg>
   <trkpt lon="11.487967" lat="0.332443"><ele>319.0</ele></trkpt>
   <trkpt lon="11.488969" lat="0.332369"><ele>318.0</ele></trkpt>
   <trkpt lon="11.494446" lat="0.331905"><ele>309.0</ele></trkpt>
   <trkpt lon="11.499806" lat="0.331473"><ele>317.0</ele></trkpt>
  </trkseg>
 </trk>
</gpx>
```

Javascript:

```
var startpoint = 0;
var endpoint = startpoint + 2;
var distance = new ol.geom.LineString(coordsarray[0].slice(startpoint,endpoint)).transform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857').getLength();
console.log(distance); // 13065083.453663955 ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var distance = new ol.geom.LineString(coordsarray[0].slice(0,i+1)).transform('EPSG:4326','????').getLength();
```

Ideally transform to a local projection such as UTM which will give meaningful meter distances.

To scale EPSG:3857 units to a latitude you can use point resolution:

```
var center = ol.geom.LineString(coordsarray[0].slice(startpoint,endpoint)).getCoordinateAt(0.5);
var units = new ol.geom.LineString(coordsarray[0].slice(startpoint,endpoint)‌​).getLength();
var distance = ol.proj.getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', units, center);
```

Over long distances spherical geometry should give a more accurate result, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html

```
var distance = ol.sphere.getLength(new ol.geom.LineString(coordsarray[0].slice(startpoint,endpoint)‌​));
```

Comment: Hi Mike. Sorry, i don't understand it. var distance = new ol.geom.LineString(coordsarray[0].slice(0,i+1)).transform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857').getLength();
console.log(distance); // example: 1234567.123456789. Is there a distance for the complete GPX route in inch?

Comment: `.getLength` will return the distance in the units of the projection you transform the geometry to.  For EPSG:3857 the units are meters, but as the scale of EPSG:3857 is true only at the equator it wouldn't give an accurate true distance anywhere outside the tropics and in somewhere like Greenland it would be meaningless.  To convert meters to inches divide by 0.0254.  `coordsarray[0].slice(0,i+1)` is the route from start to current point, `coordsarray[0].slice(i-1,i+1)` would be previous point to current point

Comment: Yes, by slice there must be (i,i+2). But, the distance is never correct. I have a example of 160 meters, and var distance = 3986643.790377662?

Comment: I have add a GPX example.

Comment: Your coordinates were already transformed to EPSG:3857 by `readFeatures` so (near the equator) `var distance = new ol.geom.LineString(coordsarray[0].slice(startpoint,endpoint)).getLength();` will return meters

Comment: Yes, already. Yet it's better. But how can i find a solution with near northpole or southpole?

Comment: You can use ol.proj.getPointResolution to adjust projection units to real distance.  If you are very close to the pole using a polar projection would be more appropriate.

Comment: With ol.proj.getPointResolution get the distance near to the calculation from brouter. I use brouter to generate GPX route files. Here are the result on three locations on earth, with a sum-distance. Equator (total elevation of 250 meter): old 384048; new 384026; brouter 385356. Pyrenees (total elevation of 200 meter): old 195186; new 142398; brouter 144047. Berlin (total elevation 15 meter): old 84080; new 50841; brouter 51280. How can i fix the distance-difference by elevation? Pythagoras?

Comment: I don't think it's elevation.  Those distance are long enough for curvature of the earth to have an effect, so using spherical (great circle) geometry would make a difference.

Comment: I have read from sphere radius. But the lengths from trkpt to next-trkpt is no time a long distance. And a distance from first-trkpt to last-trkpt is a directly linear distance. Solution? PS: don't underate the elevation. Javascript have a pythagorean(). It's not so difficult to use it. But, on this example here, it's OK without pythagorean. How can i combine PointResolution and spherical?

Comment: For sphere you must use var totaldistancesphere = ol.sphere.getLength(GPXgeometry); It's nearer to brouter, with Equator: 383596.

Comment: I have a problem with var distancesphere = ol.sphere.getDistance(coordsarray[0][0],coordsarray[0][1]); It's calculate 2524641.305429388. Also without ele in the arrays.

Comment: Ah, i must use ol.proj.transform(....., 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'); to re-transform the single coords-arrays, by using ol.sphere.getDistance().

Comment: But, the sum of all single-distances with ol.sphere.getDistance() is the same result as the total-distance ol.sphere.getLength().

Comment: ol.proj.getPointResolution() is minimal longer than ol.sphere.getDistance().